# What is the best way to keep Mediaplayer alive for a long period Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm creating a Music app where it loops a same track for n number of times. So what is the best way to keep it playing for long. Should I create and play Mediaplayer in a background service or in Activity. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Put MediaPlayer in Background service. Especially if activity wont be visible.